# Add unique conditional constraint to exsiting table

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I want to add a unique conditional constraint to an existing table in oracle but I get an error.

```
ALTER TABLE T_EVENTATTENDEE ADD CONSTRAINT EVENT_ATTENDEE_UNIQUE UNIQUE (CASE WHEN C_DELETED = 0 THEN ( F_USER, F_EVENT ) ELSE null END);
```

and error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: Just a guess, you cant return a tuple from a case expression. Try UNIQUE (CASE WHEN C_DELETED = 0 THEN F_EVENT ELSE null END, F_USER);

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini wrong guess. UNIQUE can  only handle a list of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about unique **index** instead? As you'd use a `case` expression, that would be a function-based index.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table t_eventattendee
  2    (f_user    number,
  3     f_event   number,
  4     c_deleted number
  5    );

Table created.
```

Index:

```
SQL> create unique index ui1 on t_eventattendee
  2   (CASE WHEN C_DELETED = 0 THEN  F_USER||'~'||F_EVENT  ELSE null END);

Index created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (1, 1, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (1, 1, 0);
insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (1, 1, 0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UI1) violated


SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (1, 1, 5);

1 row created.
```

---

This is why there's a *delimiter* in index (this: `F_USER||'~'||F_EVENT`):

```
SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (2, 22, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (22, 2, 0);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Because, if we omit delimiter (see whether it makes sense; if data contains `~` character, use something that doesn't exist), then the above example - combination of [2, 22] and [22, 2] would evaluate to [222] in both cases which means that you'd get false unique index violation:

```
SQL> create unique index ui1 on t_eventattendee
  2   (CASE WHEN C_DELETED = 0 THEN  F_USER||F_EVENT  ELSE null END);   --> no delimiter

Index created.

SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (2, 22, 0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (22, 2, 0);
insert into t_eventattendee(f_user, f_event, c_deleted) values (22, 2, 0)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UI1) violated


SQL>
```

Comment: Use 2x virtual columns that show a value when `c_deleted=0` then create a Unique Index on them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE__CJADJGEC),

Oracle® Database
SQL Language Reference
19c
E96310-20
January 2023

adding a constraint uses the following syntax:

> [ **CONSTRAINT** constraint_name ]
> { **UNIQUE** (column [, column ]...)
> | **PRIMARY KEY** (column [, column ]...)
> | **FOREIGN KEY** (column [, column ]...) references_clause
> | **CHECK** (condition)
> } [ constraint_state ]

so except for check-constraints you can only use a list of columns as argument.